# Ajax Get in jQuery not working in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a problem with Ajax not  get request not working in my spring mvc application. Here I have to load form elements dynamically using Ajax way on click of a button. My code goes as below.

ResourcePipeline.jsp:

```
<head>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var resourcePosition = 0;
    $('#addResourceButton').click(function() {
      resourcePosition++;
      alert(resourcePosition);
      $.get("appendResourceView.page", { fieldId: resourcePosition}, function(data){
        $('#submitRow').before(data);
        alert(resourcePosition+ "after sending the url");
      });
    });
  });
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="addResourceButton" value="+" />
</body>
```

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/appendResourceView.page")
    protected String appendResourceField(@RequestParam Integer fieldId, ModelMap model)
    {   
        System.out.println(fieldId + "from ajax call");
        model.addAttribute("resourceNumber", fieldId);
        return "resourceInsert.view";
    }
```

I think the jQuery Ajax call is not reaching my controller. But I am not sure. The first alert box in my jQuery snippet is working fine. But my second alert inside function(data) is not getting fired. Also `system.out.println` in my controller is also not getting printed. But when I enter the url manually like

```
> http://localhost:8080/das/appendResourceView.page.
```

apache is throwing some error like "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect". Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does debugger say?

Comment: Sorry Alex I am not getting you. Which debugger you are talking about? firefox or eclipse.

Comment: Firefox debugger. Did you try setting a breakpoint in the callback function to see if it reaches it?  Did you take a look to see what response code you get from the AJAX call?  success (200) or failure (4xx or 500)?

Comment: No Sotirios. Adding / also is not working.

Comment: You can't sent just `http://localhost:8080/das/appendResourceView.page`, you are missing the request parameter. `http://localhost:8080/das/appendResourceView.page?fieldId=42`

Comment: Thank you Sotirios. Something is happening now when I enter the URL manually. But why the url is not getting fired automatically.

Comment: Do I have to include any special kind of library to get that URL triggered.